# Adjust a value in jquery table with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can somebody help me I want to change the css of the 1's with the .each function. I have problems with $(this). I think I'm close but how do you compare the value of a `<p>` in an if statement?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p").each(function(i) {
    if (this.text == "1") {
      $(this).css('color', 'red');
    } else {
      $(this).css('color', 'yellow');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>1</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>2</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>3</p>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>1</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>2</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>3</p>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>1</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>2</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>3</p>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("p").each(function(i){
  if ( $(this).text().trim() == "1" ) {  //Changed here
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
  } else {
    $(this).css('color', 'yellow');
  }
 });
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/akzu65he/)

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong 'this', you need $(this) on line 3. You were also missing '()' from your text function call.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("p").each(function(){
      if ( $(this).text() === "1" ) {
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
      } else {
        $(this).css('color', 'yellow');
      }
     });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$("p").filter(function() { return $(this).text().trim() === "1" }).css("color", "red")
```

Use a simple CSS rule to make everything else yellow:

```
p {
  color:yellow
}
```